# Why does this angular-ui TypeAhead code return all items instead of filtered items?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I am trying out the angular-ui typeahead directive. The desired result is the input box should show only the filtered items based on what has been typed. My code displays all the items.

I have created a plunker for the code at http://plnkr.co/edit/8uecuPiVqmEy6gFQYeXC

What is wrong with it? Thank you very much.

Just in case you cannot access plunker, the relevant html code is like this;

```
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <h4>Testing angular-ui Typeahead</h4>
    <!-- <pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre> -->
    <input type="text" ng-model="typeahead" typeahead="names for names in getName($viewValue) " class="form-control">    
</div>
```

The relevant JS code is like this;

```
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http) 
{
  // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously  
  $scope.getName = function(val) 
  {
    return $http.get('test.json') 
    .then(function(res)
    {
        var names = [];
        angular.forEach(res.data, function(item)
        {
            names.push(item.name);
        });
        return names;
    });
  };
}
```

The json file from http get looks like this;

```
[
{
    "name": "Tom"   
},
{
    "name": "Tom2"  
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you always returning unfiltered array, most likly that can by done on servers side, but if array is static you can do this like below:

http://plnkr.co/edit/kxOlmnjGA7wX7zhS67aK?p=preview

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http) {
  // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously  
  $scope.getName = function(val) {
    return $http.get('test.json')
      .then(function(res) {
        var names = [];
        angular.forEach(res.data, function(item) {
          if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            names.push(item.name);
          } else {
            console.log(item);
          }
        });
        return names;
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: May I ask your opinion whether it would be better to do the filtering on the server side or by front-end angularjs?

Comment: Depends how much data you've got, but usually is better on server side to reduce amount of data passed from server to client